# PECL install/phpize error

Tags: php, pecl, pcre

This is my PHP setup

```
##################################################################
# setup PHP
##################################################################

# we use this to make inline CSS in newsletter
yum install php php-tidy php-xml php-xmlrpc php-gd -y

# if make is missing
yum install gcc automake autoconf libtool make -y

# configuring php pecl http
yum install zlib-devel curl-devel php-devel php-pear -y

# required by phpMyAdmin
yum install php-mcrypt php-mbstring php-bcmath pcre -y

pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
pecl upgrade

pecl install bbcode
pecl install pecl_http
pecl install apc
pecl install oauth

# add to /etc/php.ini

extension=bbcode.so
extension=http.so
extension=apc.so
extension=oauth.so

apc.shm_size="128MB"
```

Unfortunately, when I run

```
pecl install oauth
```

I get:

```
[root@server ~]# pecl install oauth
downloading oauth-1.1.0.tgz ...
Starting to download oauth-1.1.0.tgz (44,731 bytes)
............done: 44,731 bytes
6 source files, building
ERROR: could not chdir to /var/tmp/oauth/examples
```

Well, say I create the directory.

```
[root@server ~]# mkdir /var/tmp/oauth
[root@server ~]# mkdir /var/tmp/oauth/examples
[root@server ~]# pecl install oauth
downloading oauth-1.1.0.tgz ...
Starting to download oauth-1.1.0.tgz (44,731 bytes)
............done: 44,731 bytes
6 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

ERROR: `phpize' failed
[root@server ~]#
```

uh. I give up on this one. Been trying to fix it for the last few hours.

More info.

```
[root@server ~]# phpize -v
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

And

```
[root@server ~]# find / -name "config.m4"
[root@server ~]#
```

Comment: Are you able to find/execute the `phpize` binary? Is it in your `$PATH`? Does `config.m4` exist? (etc……)

Comment: What is my `$PATH`?

Comment: Enlightenment. Peace.

Comment: @Guy, try `echo $path` and `where phpize`, see if the outputs have a common directory.

Comment: At the prompt, try "echo $PATH"

Comment: What distro and version are you trying to install this on?

Comment: Ok. It is actually PECL bug. See their website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a PECL bug. ( http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16746 )

The solution is given on the PECL page.

Answer (score 0):

download the library you are looking for manually, say `PDO_MYSQL-1.0.2.tgz`. untar it and go into directory PD0_MYSQL-1.0.2. Run `phpize`. It will be installed.